# Why isn't this LINQ parsing a file properly?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a file with a simple `key,value` format, one per line.
e.g:

```
word1,filepath1
word2,filepath2
word3,filepath5
```

I'm trying to read this into a `Dictionary<string,string>` in one go with LINQ. There are some duplicates in the file (where the first part - the first string - is the duplicate). In this case, I'm ok with dropping the duplicates.

This is my LINQ which isn't working:

```
var indexes = File.ReadAllLines(indexFileName)
    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
    .GroupBy(x=>x[0])
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ElementAt(1));
```

The `ToDictionary` part is confusing me, how do I retrieve the first value from the group and assign it to the value of the dictionary?

I get a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.'` exception.

Comment: so the above code is not working, any erros?

Comment: It sounds like it isn't working how you're expecting it to. What does that give you?

Comment: *how do I retrieve the first value from the group* -- the aptly named `First()` method would be my go-to choice.

Comment: @EricLippert I suppose it was `.First()[0]` that I was really after! Thanks

Comment: @EricLippert I personally prefer `.FirstOrDefault()` so it doesn't error when what you're calling it on is empty, then testing the result for null.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's not that obvious except in hindsight.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Because the answer was in the question - "how do I retrieve the `first` value"

Comment: @Andrew That's not the answer. The answer is that he needs to return the *second element of the first value*.

Comment: Do you just want the first value that matches the keys or do you just want the distinct set of keys?

Comment: @Andrew: How is it possible for a child sequence of a group-by query to be *empty* ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var indexes = File.ReadAllLines(indexFileName)
                    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
                    .GroupBy(x => x[0])
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First()[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

So the problem here is that you're grouping arrays, not strings. Therefore the group objects you're dealing with in the `ToDictionary()` lambda are enumerations of *arrays*, not of strings. `g.ElementAt(0)` isn't a string. It's the first array of strings:

When

```
g.Key == "word1"
```

then `g.ElementAt(0)` is...

```
{ "word1", "filepath1" }
```

So you want `g.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(1)`, or `g.First()[0]`, or something to that effect.

That seems painfully obvious in hindsight, but unfortunately *only* in hindsight, for me.

I would suggest that after you accept Matthew Whited's answer, you clarify the code by turning the split lines into anonymous objects as soon as you can. `ElementAt(1)` doesn't communicate much.

```
var indexes =
     File.ReadAllLines(indexFileName)
    .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
    //  Turn the array into something self-documenting
    .Select(a => new { Word = a[0], Path = a[1] })
    .GroupBy(o => o.Word)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().Path)
    ;
```

Converting each line to an object makes it easier for me to think about, and Intellisense starts playing on your team as well.

Comment: Nicely done.  Aside, it is safe to First a group, as there will always be at least one member.

Comment: @DavidB Right, it wouldn't be there if there weren't at least one member, would it? Thanks! And thanks for spotting that stray `x`.